# WPF ViewModel Issue

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a recursive viewmodel that uses for a treeview. The problem is everytime I delete a Group Item or Entry Item. The treeview cannot reflect the change immediately until I force it by treeview.Items.Refresh(). My guess is the ObservableCollection Items did get notified. Could you one please point me out. Thanks.

ViewModel

```
public class Group:ViewModelBase
{
    private int _key;

    public int Key
    {
        get { return _key; }
        set { _key = value; OnPropertyChanged("Key"); }
    }
    private string _name;

    public string Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set { _name = value; OnPropertyChanged("Name"); }
    }
    private bool _isexpanded;

    public bool IsExpanded
    {
        get { return _isexpanded; }
        set { _isexpanded = value; OnPropertyChanged("IsExpanded"); }
    }
    private int _order;

    public int Order
    {
        get { return _order; }
        set { _order = value; OnPropertyChanged("Order"); }
    }
    private int _grouporder;

    public int GroupOrder
    {
        get { return _grouporder; }
        set { _grouporder = value; OnPropertyChanged("GroupOrder"); }
    }
    private string _error;

    public string Error
    {
        get { return _error; }
        set { _error = value; OnPropertyChanged("Error"); }
    }
    private ObservableCollection<Group> _subgroups;

    public ObservableCollection<Group> SubGroups
    {
        get { return _subgroups; }
        set { _subgroups = value; 
            OnPropertyChanged("SubGroups");
            OnPropertyChanged("Entries");
        }
    }
    private ObservableCollection<Entry> _entries;

    public ObservableCollection<Entry> Entries
    {
        get { return _entries; }
        set { _entries = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("SubGroups");
            OnPropertyChanged("Entries"); }
    }


    public ObservableCollection<object> Items
    {
        get
        {
            ObservableCollection<object> childNodes = new ObservableCollection<object>();
            foreach (var entry in this.Entries)
                childNodes.Add(entry);
            foreach (var group in this.SubGroups)
                childNodes.Add(group);
            return childNodes;
        }

    }
}
```

Binding:

```
 public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        treeview.ItemsSource = Groups;
        this.DataContext = this;


    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you break the link with the original collections.

So I can imagine two solutions:

1) Register for changes on `Entries` and `SubGroups` and apply them back to `Items`:

```
private ObservableCollection<object> items;
public ObservableCollection<object> Items
{
    get
    {
        if (items == null)
        {
            items = new ObservableCollection<object>();
            foreach (var entry in this.Entries)
                items.Add(entry);
            foreach (var group in this.SubGroups)
                items.Add(group);


            this.Entries.CollectionChanged += (s, a) =>
            {
                if (/*add some stuff*/)
                {
                    items.Add(/*some stuff*/)
                }
                else if (/*remove some stuff*/)
                {
                    items.Remove(...)
                }
            };

            this.SubGroups.CollectionChanged += ...

            return items;
        }
    }
}
```

And you would reset `items` by setting it to `null` each time you set `Entries` or `SubGroups` so that it is regenerated next time, taking into account new `Entries` and `SubGroups`.

2) Try with a `CompositeCollection`:

```
new CompositeCollection
{
    new CollectionContainer { Collection = this.Entries },
    new CollectionContainer { Collection = this.SubGroups }
};
```

Not sure for this second solution but it would be quite elegant, worth a try...

Comment: Right. Never set an ObservableCollection<T> property, always call Clear() and Add(), otherwise you are overwriting the binding info.

Comment: @Pragmateek, Thanks!!you saved my day. I went with the compositecollection!!